# while in debug in an rspec feature spec, how can I get the server to refresh when I make a change?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I frequently develop while writing rspec feature tests, using debug.pry to pause execution and look at the "state" of the app in the browser, make adjustments, and look at data from the debug prompt.

When I change a rails file in development mode, I don't have to restart the server to see the change, but when I change a file after the spec has run, and I'm at the debug prompt, is there a way to "reload!" the server so I don't have to re-run the test? This is quite time-consuming. I'd just like to refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was easy it turns out:

```
  config.cache_classes = false  # turn off to be able to reload browser
```

I'll just leave this for posterity.